# Is concurrent code in JMX services allowed?

Tags: multithreading, service, concurrency, jboss, jmx

The EJB 3.1 Spec. states:

> The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage threads.

The JBoss EJB 3 Extensions Reference states:

> [JMX services] are singleton beans...

So I reason:

1. Using a multithreaded 3rd-party lib in a JMX Service is not conform
   to the Spec.
2. A JMX service is a wrapper for a EJB 3.1 Singleton Bean with additional management capabilities provided through the JMX console.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss AS will (currently!) not prevent the use of threads in an EJB.

A JMX service (MBean) is not related to EJB; threads are allowed in JMX.

@Service beans are implemented with a JMX wrapper. They are a proprietary extension to EJBs and so do not conform to the EJB spec. They are kind of a hybrid between EJBs and JMX MBeans.

@Service beans are not related to EJB 3.1 Singleton Beans. Although being similar, they were around before EJB 3.1 existed.

Comment: What version of JBoss are you referring to when you say "currently"? We found out that the Service annotation does not work anymore with AS-7. Instead, we write Startup-Singletons that register themselves with the JMX-Server in a PostConstruct method. The code for this registration is injected using Weld. Those MBeans manage their own threads and make calls to EJB session beans which do not manage any threads, so we are clean w.r.t. the EJB spec.

Comment: I am referring to JBoss AS 6.0. You are correct, @Service is not working any longer with AS 7. Thanks for your solution for AS 7 :).